# Is there a small no frills EventSource client?

Tags: java, html, http, scala

I'm building an app optimized for embedded devices, and I need an [`EventSource`](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) client (commonly called SSE) to connect to a server.

Is there something which isn't a full blown library with unneeded code, but just a simple EventSource client either for Java or Scala?

For unneeded code I mean code that doesn't initialize or reserve data/CPU for other functions of the library. Eg. If I need EventSource I don't want the library to initialize/reserve/load WebRTC or Websocket stuff.

Comment: What constitutes "unneeded code" for you? Every library has code because *someone* needed it. Without a more clear understanding of your specific requirements, it may be impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @Flimzy for unneeded code I mean code that doesn't initialize or reserve data/CPU for other functions of the library. Eg. If I need EventSource I don't want the library to initialize/reserve/load WebRTC or Websocket stuff.